# How can I bind a GtkBox to an array?

Tags: gtk3, gjs

I'm making some GTK desktop widgets which monitors stuff like System Tray elements or opened windows for the taskbar.

For the taskbar, an approach I'm taking is re-populate a Gtk.Box each time I get a "change" signal from my window manager: I remove everything from the GtkBox and then I re-add everything based on a query I perform against the window manager after the state change. This way I don't have to worry about ordering or missed signals.

However, I'm wondering if there's a way to make a `Gtk.Box` bound to an array so that it handles changes by itself. `FlowBox` has a `bind_model` method which seems to fit my use case, but `FlowBox` also seems more complex than a simple `Box`: doesn't `Box` (or `Container`, or `Widget`) provide a similar mechanism?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`GtkBox` does not support a feature like this, as it is intended to be a simple container widget.

Widgets like `GtkListBox` and `GtkFlowBox` do by supporting being bound to a [`GListModel`](https://docs.gtk.org/gio/iface.ListModel.html). But neither the widgets nor the list model operate any complex logic; the list model tracks the position and number members, emits an `items-changed` signal. The `GtkListBox` and `GtkFlowBox` track the member widgets, and respond to the signal.

If you're concerned about performance, you should just implement `GListModel` for your use case and bind it to a `GtkListBox` or `GtkFlowBox`. You can then emit `items-changed` with the `position`, `removed` and `added` parameters to reflect only the real changes.